# powerpoint run macro every time presentation hits first slide

Tags: macros, powerpoint

I am have a macro running in my powerpoint presentation (2007) to update all of the linked excel data. The macro works perfectly if I run it manually but I am trying to set it to run automatically every time the presentation gets back to the first slide.

I put the following code together after looking through a few similar questions here but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens when I hit slide 1.

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = 1 Then

Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
On Error Resume Next
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
oshp.LinkFormat.update
Next oshp
Next osld

End If
End Sub
```

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct and should work, but PowerPoint sometimes doesn't properly implement OnSlideShowPageChange.

Adding an ActiveX control to the slide (even off-slide) usually solves the problem.

Comment: Aha, that did work, and in the process it helped me find the problem. My slideshow apparently doesnt have a slide "1" and started at 5 for some reason. Only found that out when I opened the ActiveX element. I have now changed it and the code works without the need for ActiveX. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm curious as to why that might be. CurrentShowPosition should return the position within the current show (of course) or the position within a Custom show if you're in one of those, but either way, the show would normally start with 1.  Of course, if you're looking at slide 5 and start the show there, you'll never get to 1 unless you back up.