# Advance to a slide at a certain time

Tags: datetime, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint show that I would like to be running. At 13:30, I would like the show to automatically move onto slide 9. Is this possible? Please could any answers be detailed as I have not been using coding or developer in PowerPoint for long.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for starters:
[powerpoint run macro every time presentation hits first slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899956/powerpoint-run-macro-every-time-presentation-hits-first-slide)

It explains how you can run a bit of code every time the slide changes.  Instead of the code shown there, you'd do something like:

```
If Format(NOW,"hh:mm") = "13:30" Then
  ' Aircode Warning!
  SlideShowWindows(1).View.GoToSlide(9)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SteveRindsberg Where do I need to put this code?

Comment: Did you follow the link in my reply?